# Как удалить консольный запускаемый файл?

Tags: c#

Перепробовал несколько вариков, сразу скажу что без скриптов! напрямую.
на форме удаляет так:

```
ProcessStartInfo Flash = new ProcessStartInfo();
            Flash.Arguments = "/C choice /C Y /N /D Y /T 3 & Del" + Application.ExecutablePath;
            Flash.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden; Flash.CreateNoWindow = true;
            Flash.FileName = "cmd.exe";Process.Start(Flash);
            Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
```

А для консоли не получается, попробовал заменить `Application.ExecutablePath` на `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase`
Но ничего не удаляется :(

Попробовал такой вариант:

```
public static void enable()
    {
        var exepath = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;
        var info = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/C choice /C Y /N /D Y /T 3 & Del" + exepath);
        info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        Process.Start(info).Dispose();
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
```

Опять не в какую, как удалить после завершения всех функций сам запускаемый файл! ???

Comment: Если вы нашли решение, то пишите его в ответ.

Comment: Да я здесь не давно, поэтому не знал..) Окей)))

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему, сделал так:

```
Flash.Arguments = "/C choice /C Y /N /D Y /T 3 & Del \"" + (new FileInfo((new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase)).LocalPath)).Name + "\"";`
```